# How to get dates out of a BSONObject or MongoDB in Julia?

Tags: julia, bson

If the following BSONObject is returned from a Mongo database, how to get the "d" date out of this object, at least the unix date integer/posix number? I am trying to use the pzion/Mongo.jl and pzion/LibBSON.jl versions from github to connect to a Mongo database.

`doc = BSONObject({ "_id" : { "$oid" : "55d8f6b1f69dbaebaacd7e58" }, "d" : { "$date" : 1438628400000 }, "f" : 0.25, "s": "hello" })`

I can retrieve the float and the string by

`doc["f"]
doc["s"]`

but

`doc["d"]`

gives an error:

`LoadError: unhandled BSONType 9`